# Why the following non-static data member initialization is invalid in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initialization, variadic-templates

I have tried to compile the following small example:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Sizes>
class Foo {
public:
     const std::size_t    rank = sizeof...(Sizes);
     const std::size_t    dimensions[sizeof...(Sizes)] = { Sizes... };
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int, 1, 2, 3> foo;

    std::cout << "Rank: " << foo.rank << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile with gcc-4.8.1 complaining of a lack of `;` at end of member declaration and a lack of expected unqualified-id before `...` token. However, if I replace the two members with the following it compiles and works as expected:

```
const std::size_t     rank = 5;
const std::size_t     dimensions[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Why can I not use `sizeof...` and `Sizes...` as compile-time constants, surely both are known and evaluated at compile time and so can be used in non-static data member initialization? Moreover, if I replace `rank = 5` with `rank = sizeof(int)` it compiles and works as expected, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with `sizeof`.

---

Here is my [demonstrative ideone](http://ideone.com/Lk6cZ4).

Comment: Works on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe9dc881bef4a2c). BTW: You have a typo: `std::size` instead of `std::size_t` at the beginning!

Comment: @DanielFrey I've added my demonstrative ideone compilation; the typo was just me copying it up incorrectly haha!

Comment: Did you forget to enable C++11? At least in ideone you did. You need to change the language to C++11 in ideone. With g++ that is `-std=c++11`

Comment: Actual ideone example with c++11: http://ideone.com/WTOG4f. coliru uses gcc 4.9.0 while ideone has 4.8.1.

Comment: @leemes It stated that `-std=c++11` was enabled by default when it issued the warning telling me that it was a C++11 only feature

Comment: To support this guy, the posted code does not work on GCC 4.8.2.

Answer (score 7):

This is [gcc bug 57673](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57673) that was fixed in gcc 4.9. The fix for gcc 4.8 is to add an extra set of parentheses.

```
const std::size_t rank = (sizeof...(Sizes));
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/yoDDg6)

Comment: You can also make them into `static constexpr` instead of nonstatic members (which has some added benifits, IMHO).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams That's interesting that [changing `rank`](http://ideone.com/ax4wBE) to a static data member fixes what seems to be a parsing issue.

Comment: BUGS MAN. I'm guessing since using static const values are more common (mostly because if it is const and always the same, why allocate the memory for it at all? Also static const is more easily resolved to a constexpr so they are probably faster) that got caught early on. They each have different rules (since inline declaration of const members has its own weird rules).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Brian, your code does work on GCC 4.9.

I found that on GCC 4.8 you can make it work by wrapping the expansion in brackets:

```
const std::size_t    rank = (sizeof...(Sizes)); // OK
```